# On Mac, how do I give myself permanent sudo privleges?

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

In Mac OS X 10.6, how do I give myself permanent sudo privleges?
is it like linux, in the "/etc/sudoers" file?

Comment: You know that sudo is there for a reason, right?  The idea is to give access to superuser privileges without being constantly logged in as root (not a good idea).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not exactly experienced in OSX, but it seems to be located in either one of the following:

> - /etc/sudoers
> - /private/etc/sudoers

It is recommended that you use visudo to edit the file but you can use another text editor.

Under the line that says `root ALL=(ALL) ALL`

You add the name of the user and `user ALL=(ALL) ALL`to give yourself permanent sudo privileges.

Comment: `ls -ld /etc` results in `lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 30 Jun  2010 /etc -> private/etc`, so they're both the same file.

Comment: yea, I did it in fedora a while ago.. It seems to be the same process, but thanks.. didn't wanna just go haphazardly changing important system file :D

Comment: On OSX at least, you execute just `sudo visudo` to edit the sudoers file (don't specify the file.)

Answer (score 5):

You can, of course, edit `/etc/sudoers` manually to accomplish this.

But Mac OS X's *System Preferences* has a method built-in to achieve the same thing: Give the user an *Administrator* account, instead of a *Standard* account, and it will be added to `/etc/sudoers` as sudoer automatically (via the `wheel` group membership).

Users will still need to enter their own password though, which is a good thing <sup>(tm)</sup>.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that in fedora, but I wanted to ask before I did it, so I didn't break anything.. thanks

Comment: Wait, aren't there other special privelages that come with giving a user an "Administrator" account other than just that it adds them to the sudoers file?

Comment: @cmcculloh It's not *adding the account to the sudoers file*, but *membership in the `wheel` and `admin` groups*, complete with e.g. write permissions to `/Applications` and comparable other global folders. Just compare the output of e.g. `id` in Terminal of normal and admin users.

Comment: I discovered you need to enable root access in MacOSX 10.8. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012

Answer (score 2):

sudo in OSX is exactly like that under Linux, and like Linux [man sudo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) shows the details

> sudo determines who is an authorized user by consulting the file /private/etc//sudoers.

/etc is a symbolic link to /private/etc so your suggestion of /etc/sudoers will work.

Answer (score 2):

You could as well run `sudo -s`

This will give you root permissions for that session.

To return to normal permissions, just type `exit`

Comment: This answer is pretty awesome. There's definite use cases for having sudo access for just a session.